# What's wrong with my code of regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main(){
  regex rule("(?<test>\\d+)");
  string str = "11.22.33.44";
  boost::smatch result;
  string::const_iterator start = str.begin();
  string::const_iterator end = str.end();
  while (regex_search(start, end, result, rule))
    {
     std::cout << result['test'].str() << std::endl;// here 
     start = result['test'].second;// it seems it work 
    }
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Why it didn't work correctly? 
I'm used to using PHP to do that. 
How can I make my code work?
the aim of the code is to match the each number in the regex named group.

Comment: It's awfully hard to say why it "didn't work the right way" considering you did not describe what you are trying to do...

Comment: There is an explicit reason to close your question since it is `off-topic`  because of `why this code isn't working`. Community can't guess what you want to do and debug your code.

Comment: Aside from this is C++, and `'text'` means 't', its best practice to name the regex object with some `rx_` prefix and the match object `m_` so its readable. Also, its better to set the _new_ start position at the end of the entire match, not capture group's > 0. (ie. `start = _m[0].second;`)

Answer (score 1):

`'test'` is a character literal. You want to use a string literal: use `"test"`

Besides, use compiler warnings:

```
test.cpp|13 col 29| warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
||          std::cout << result['test'].str() << std::endl; // here
```

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d131b259158f0a6)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main() {
    regex rule("(?<test>\\d+)");
    string str = "11.22.33.44";
    boost::smatch result;
    string::const_iterator start = str.begin();
    string::const_iterator end = str.end();
    while (regex_search(start, end, result, rule)) {
        std::cout << result["test"].str() << std::endl;
        start = result["test"].second;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
11
22
33
44
```